# how to response after media scanner complete its event

Tags: java, android, android-mediascanner

I am having problem with media scanner, in my program i am running media scanner through...

`sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));`

this above code works but it runs as async which is bit paining for me.

Is there any way to stop till mediascanner complete it's work.

i am fetching list of music file from the sd card, and the problem is list is getting fetched before mediascanner return it's result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, you could use Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED instead.

You can find all the intents you want [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN).